# No storage mechanism for grants specified

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am new to IdentityServer and am having a little trouble setting this up.

For reasons I won't go into here I can't use ASP.NET Identity or EntityFramework.  I have a custom database for users that I need to authenticate against so I took the samples and tried to switch out the InMemoryUsers for a custom persistence store.

Here is my ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.AuthenticationOptions = new IdentityServer4.Configuration.AuthenticationOptions
            {
            };
        })
    .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
    .AddInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get())
    .SetTemporarySigningCredential();

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddTransient<ISignInService, SignInService>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();

    services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
    services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
}
```

I know this method is imperfect as I am still testing some things, but when I run the application I get this error:

System.InvalidOperationException
No storage mechanism for grants specified. Use the 'AddInMemoryStores' extension method to register a development version.

Obviously I don't want to use in memory stores for a production implementation, but I am not sure what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: Don't force tags into question title http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AddInMemoryStores does not have the best name. It actually adds the store for all the transient data that relates to issued materials/tokens.

We use it in production sometimes because a lot of the time we don't really need to persist this data to disk, and we don't use long lived tokens.

Take a look at what the extension method does [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4/Configuration/DependencyInjection/BuilderExtensions/InMemory.cs#L81) and look at what the `IPersistedGrantStore` contract looks like to get a better idea.

Comment: the extension method link you provided has gone. I am facing the same problem, can you check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797993/identityserver-4-no-storage-mechanism-for-grants-specified-use-addinmemorysto]

Comment: @h.salman the APIs changed literally in the last couple of weeks. Thanks for letting me know I changed the URL

Comment: Posted link seems dead ;(